# Show wpf application on startup in taskbar without using System.Windows.Application

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen, taskbar

Our application does not appear in the taskbar on startup, because it is a WPF window displayed over `ShowDialog` but not using `System.Windows.Application`. Is it possible to show the app in the taskbar?

```
var spl = new SplashScreen();  // Nothing in the taskbar, but it should...
spl.ShowDialog();

// initial application

spl.Close();

var app = new App();
app.Run(mainWindow);   // Now we have some thing in the taskbar
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sp1 = SplashScreen();    
sp1.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

Comment: The answer was so easy, i did not get it: `splash.ShowInTaskbar = true;` thats all. If you add this to your answer, i will accept it. So this question will be closed.